# Python: How to call super when the class itself has a decorator?

Tags: python, inheritance, wrapper, decorator, super

I need to call the inherited class to get it's content and methods to work. But I also have a class decorator assigned to my wrapper classes. I have a lot of wrapper classes and want them to be as short as possible, that's why I try to get this to work.

```
@add_properties
class Item01Object(BaseItemObject):
    properties=["quantum","size","mass"]

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(Item01Object, self).__init__(name)

    #[...]

@add_properties
class Item02Object(BaseItemObject):
    #[...]
```

But when I instance my class, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\wrapper.py", line 862, in __init__
super(Item01Object, self).__init__(name)
NameError: global name 'Item01Object' is not defined
```

The idea:

1. Quick edit of each "wrapper" item's properties with it's class variable `properties`
2. Base functionality given by the `BaseItemObject`
3. Methods could be easily overwritten
4. Short wrapper classes to have a good overview

How could I make it work??

Thanks.

Comment: @ Martijn: Sorry, I edited my question, now it gots the error message

Comment: Ahh.. again, sorry. I should better reread what I was writing. Now the error is the same like I have inside the application.

Comment: The code as posted won't reproduce that error though. The global `Item01Object` *is* defined in the code; the `class` statement returned a new class, and after being passed through the class decorator Python bound the name `Item01Object` to the result.

Comment: Your code did something *else* to unbind that global again.

Comment: Ya, I was using the class decorator's function with a wrong return value. I will read the documentation of using decorators again, that I will not post those simple mistakes again. Anyway, thanks for your quick reply!!

Comment: Yes, in my answer to your previous question, the class decorator I gave you returns the class again. If you try to create an instance of the class in that decorator then the global name is not *yet* bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I solved it. Was a really simple mistake. In `add_properties` I returned the object of my class, but it needs to return the class itself. So my constructor was executed before my class was completely build. So I just changed it to the following and it works fine:

```
def add_properties( ItemObject ):
    for propName, cls in PropertyContainer.__dict__.iteritems():
        if propName in ItemObject.properties:
            setattr(ItemObject, propName, cls.__dict__[propName])
    return ItemObject # <- Do not return an object!!
```

This is the first time I am using a lot of decorators in a complex structure, but I really like the idea and the structure I get with it.